# Check if a file exist in the Server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, file, c#-2.0

```
        string jSFile = ResolveUrl("~/MyProject/JavaScripts/dir/test.js");
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(jSFile))
        {
           ...
        }
```

This code **doesn't work** and I guess it's the jSFile that doesn't work well with the IO.File.Exists but I know the jSFile has a valid path because when I use few line later

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myfile",jSFile);
```

it does attach the JavaScript file to the ASPX and all work fine.

Any idea of how to check if the file exist?

Comment: You should have indicated that the code is inside a UserControl.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(jSFile)))
```

Comment: What is the namespace of Server.MapPath?

Comment: If you are inside of the web context, it should map automatically, otherwise you would use the full path.

Comment: @Daok: Look at your inheritance tree.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath();

Comment: I think this answer is good BUT more I read about MapPathSecure and more I think it's better to use it when possible before using MapPath. What you think?

Comment: I think now that you know the options you will make the right choice. ;)